# SQL select distinct by max(value) over multiple tables

Tags: sql, select, join, max, distinct

I have a problem in a part of my own application. Simplified it is a kind of message service where somebody can send a message to a pool and another one can receive an unread message within the pool. It is important to mention, that if anyone receives a message he will get a preview. If he decides to not keep that message, he can put it back to the pool of available messages.

**What I need**

- One sql command to list all my sended messages (paramater: logintoken) with content, timestamp and username of receiver (if there is any)
- One sql command to list all my received messages (paramater: logintoken) with username of sender, message, creation_date and receiving_date

**What the database scheme looks like**

Table "message": id:int, arrived:bit, content:varchar, creation_timestamp:String (dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss), opened:bit

- arrived is set to true when someone received the message (small overview)
- opened is set to true when someone read the whole message

Table "route": id:int, timestamp (see above), id_message, id_user

- a route is created everytime a user creates a message
- id_user can be the creator or the receiver
- they are non-updatable

Table "session": token:varchar, user_id:int

Table "user": id:int, username:varchar, [...]

**Example data**

```
SELECT id, username FROM user
+----+----------+
| id | username  |
+----+-----------+
| 32 | userx     |
| 33 | usery     |
| 34 | userz     |
| 35 | usertest  |
| 36 | usertest2 |
| 37 | usertest3 |
| 38 | usertest4 |
+----+-----------+

SELECT * FROM session

+--------------------------------------+---------------+---------+
|                token                 | creationTime  | user_id |
+--------------------------------------+---------------+---------+
| 35107851-3ae6-40c7-8b4a-662a407ff2dc | 1526046557203 |      32 |
| 426c752a-7ad9-4bf0-b8db-1489904af495 | 1526046557267 |      36 |
| 42de6f78-6257-4014-a349-53702cb3adc0 | 1526046557277 |      37 |
| 7a3d46ed-9113-4030-8bcf-906cf2e361a7 | 1526046557346 |      38 |
| c8e7921e-fb5a-4a6e-9cd6-4a7d24e30129 | 1526046557226 |      35 |
+--------------------------------------+---------------+---------+

SELECT * FROM messages

+----+---------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+--------+
| id | arrived |            content            |       timestamp       | opened |
+----+---------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+--------+
|  2 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr1"  | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
|  3 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr2"  | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
|  4 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr3"  | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
|  5 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr4"  | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
|  6 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr5"  | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
|  7 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr6"  | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
|  8 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr7"  | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
|  9 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr8"  | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 10 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr9"  | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 11 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr10" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 12 |       1 | "This is a testmessage. Nr11" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 13 |       1 | "This is a testmessage. Nr12" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 14 |       1 | "This is a testmessage. Nr13" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 15 |       1 | "This is a testmessage. Nr14" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 16 |       1 | "This is a testmessage. Nr15" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 17 |       1 | "This is a testmessage. Nr16" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 18 |       1 | "This is a testmessage. Nr17" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 19 |       1 | "This is a testmessage. Nr18" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 20 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr19" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 21 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr20" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 22 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr21" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 23 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr22" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 24 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr23" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 25 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr24" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 26 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr25" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 27 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr26" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 28 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr27" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 29 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr28" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 30 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr29" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
| 31 |       0 | "This is a testmessage. Nr30" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" |      0 |
+----+---------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+--------+

SELECT * from route

+----+-----------------------+------------+---------+
| id |       timestamp       | id_message | id_user |
+----+-----------------------+------------+---------+
| 39 | "11-05-2018 15:49:17" |          1 |      33 |
| 40 | "11-05-2018 15:49:17" |          2 |      35 |
| 41 | "11-05-2018 15:49:17" |          3 |      35 |
| 42 | "11-05-2018 15:49:17" |          4 |      35 |
| 43 | "11-05-2018 15:49:17" |          5 |      35 |
| 44 | "11-05-2018 15:49:17" |          6 |      35 |
| 45 | "11-05-2018 15:49:17" |          7 |      35 |
| 46 | "11-05-2018 15:49:17" |          8 |      35 |
| 47 | "11-05-2018 15:49:17" |          9 |      35 |
| 48 | "11-05-2018 15:49:17" |         10 |      35 |
| 49 | "11-05-2018 15:49:17" |         11 |      35 |
| 50 | "11-05-2018 15:49:17" |         12 |      36 |
| 51 | "11-05-2018 15:49:17" |         13 |      36 |
| 52 | "11-05-2018 15:49:17" |         14 |      36 |
| 53 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         15 |      36 |
| 54 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         16 |      36 |
| 55 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         17 |      36 |
| 56 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         18 |      36 |
| 57 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         19 |      36 |
| 58 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         20 |      36 |
| 59 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         21 |      36 |
| 60 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         22 |      37 |
| 61 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         23 |      37 |
| 62 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         24 |      37 |
| 63 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         25 |      37 |
| 64 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         26 |      37 |
| 65 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         27 |      37 |
| 66 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         28 |      37 |
| 67 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         29 |      37 |
| 68 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         30 |      37 |
| 69 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         31 |      37 |
| 70 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         12 |      35 |
| 71 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         13 |      35 |
| 72 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         14 |      35 |
| 73 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         15 |      35 |
| 74 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         16 |      35 |
| 75 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         17 |      35 |
| 76 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         18 |      35 |
| 77 | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |         19 |      35 |
+----+-----------------------+------------+---------+
```

**Expected result**

1. For my messages

```
SELECT ... WHERE token = (in this case: 42de6f78-6257-4014-a349-53702cb3adc0)

+------------+-------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| id_message | receiver_username |        message_content        |     creation_date     |   last_forward_date   |
+------------+-------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|         60 | NULL              | "This is a testmessage. Nr21" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" | "11-05-2018 15:49:18" |
|         61 | NULL              | "This is a testmessage. Nr22" | "11-05-2018 15:49:14" | 11-05-2018 15:49:18   |
|         62 | NULL              | [...]                         | [...]                 | [...]                 |
|         63 | NULL              | [...]                         | [...]                 | [...]                 |
|         64 | NULL              | [...]                         | [...]                 | [...]                 |
|         65 | NULL              | [...]                         | [...]                 | [...]                 |
|         66 | NULL              | [...]                         | [...]                 | [...]                 |
|         67 | NULL              | [...]                         | [...]                 | [...]                 |
|         68 | NULL              | [...]                         | [...]                 | [...]                 |
|         69 | NULL              | [...]                         | [...]                 | [...]                 |
+------------+-------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

2. For received messages

```
SELECT ... WHERE token = (in this case: c8e7921e-fb5a-4a6e-9cd6-4a7d24e30129) AND message.arrived = 1 AND ...

+------------+-----------------+------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id_message | sender_username |       message_content        |    creation_date    |  last_forward_date  |
+------------+-----------------+------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|         12 | usertest2       | This is a testmessage. Nr.11 | 11-05-2018 15:49:14 | 11-05-2018 15:49:18 |
|         13 | usertest2       | This is a testmessage. Nr.12 | [...]               | [...]               | [...]               |
|         14 | usertest2       | [...]                        | [...]               | [...]               |
|         15 | usertest2       | [...]                        | [...]               | [...]               |
|         16 | usertest2       | [...]                        | [...]               | [...]               |
|         17 | usertest2       | [...]                        | [...]               | [...]               |
|         18 | usertest2       | [...]                        | [...]               | [...]               |
|         19 | usertest2       | [...]                        | [...]               | [...]               |
+------------+-----------------+------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**Hints**

I thought of maybe using SELECT DISTINCT while using JOINS for the multiple tables. In the where-clause should be something like `WHERE token = XYZZZZ

1. For my messages

The first occurence in the route table for one specific message has to be with my user_id. Something like `SELECT DISTINCT with the message_id WHERE user_id = my_id`

2. For received messages

The last occurence in the route table for one specific message has to be with my user_id and message.arrived has to be "1".

---

Nothing worked so far because I'm lacking of an idea how to implement that. Has anyone any further ideas or some tricks I can use to implement that? Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: "Ideas" and "needs" are not nearly as helpful as sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hello Gordon, thanks for your answer. I added sample data and the desired results as you suggested. I would be glad if you could have a look at that.